# Export video has different resolution Adobe Premier Pro

Tags: premiere, cs5

I try to export video in Adobe Premier Pro CS5 but it export the video using another resolution.

So for example the original video (.mov) has resolution 1920x1080, but exported video has resolution 720x560 (something like this, I don't remember it is rough resolution).

I tried to adjust size of vide in export window but the size video was another then I expected in this case as well.

Maybe you can advice some good tutorial import/export video. Many thanks

Comment: Post a screenshot of your export settings.

Comment: @DrMayhem - it's probably more than just that, the sequence settings also have to be adjusted or it will have already been scaled down before getting to the export.

Answer (score 1):

Exports will be set to the resolution of the sequence you are exporting.  You need to adjust your sequence settings to match your file input and then export.  You can do this from the sequence settings.  It should have also given you an option to update the sequence when you initially added the 1080p clip to the sequence, but you must have chosen not to update your sequence at that time.

The other, more rare, possibility is that you are using a demo codec that doesn't support 1080p for export and it is trying to export at the maximum supported resolution.  If this is the case, choosing a different codec for export should allow you to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that either your sequence or export settings don't match the imported resolution. My recommendation is that when you begin your project, your do NOT select a sequence preset but instead create a sequence from the imported video settings.

In addition, you may also be modifying your export settings to something different from your intended resolution. If your sequence is 1920 x 1080, simply find the appropriate preset, or you can even export a video that has the same settings as your sequence.